# HBase MapReduce job loads configuration (hbase-site.xml), but actually doesn't

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am writing a MapReduce job which reads from (a) HBase table(s). Almost everything works as it is supposed to except the `Configuration` class. So I did this,

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(config, args);
// This should work but is not working.
config.addResource(new Path(parser.getCommandLine().getOptionValue("conf", DEFAULT_HBASE_CONF)));
```

When I run the job like this (passing the path to `hbase-site.xml` correctly), I get this error.

```
14/06/30 23:02:30 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1075)
14/06/30 23:02:30 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

But when I add the following two lines, it works like a charm (even though it seems completely ridiculous).

```
// So these are the workarounds.
config.set("hbase.rootdir", config.get("hbase.rootdir"));
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", config.get("hbase.zookeeper.quorum"));
```

Basically, read the parameters back from the `Configuration` object and set them back in the same object, which is bonkers.

I read a bug raised about it [HBASE-11066](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11066), but it seems to have been closed citing local configuration problem (I think not) and a SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456484/) which is probably similar to my query, but with no answer yet. I use CDH 5.0.2 with HBase 0.96.1.1. Any insight would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into something similar.

Effectively: My job has 'localhost' as the hbase.zookeeper.quorum when I run it from my IDE.

The cause was that the 'yarn' and 'hadoop' scripts add the config dir (i.e. where the hbase-site.xml is located) to the classpath before starting the java runtime.
When I run from my IDE this is not done at all.

Now when you create the HBase config two files are loaded:

- hbase-default.xml: This is part of one of the hbase jars so it will always be found.
- hbase-site.xml: This is in the config dir, this config dir should be on the classpath and can overrule some of the settings from the default.

I validated this by printing the classpath from within my application using a snippet like this ([copied from here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/))

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
for(URL url: urls){
    System.out.println(url.getFile());
}
```

and by printing the result of

```
config.get("hbase.zookeeper.quorum") :
```

I suspect you have a similar issue.

One of the things I'm considering is to get the "HADOOP_CONF_DIR" environment variable and make sure it is part of the classpath and if it is not give a warning.

Comment: But I do add the `hbase-site.xml` as a resource.

Comment: The HBaseConfiguration.create(); does that too. But if it isn't on the classpath then in reality nothing gets loaded.

Comment: As far as I know `HBaseConfiguration.create();` creates a `Configuration` object with all the default values for an HBase installation. Then, when you add `hbase-site.xml` as a resource, the values are read from the file and updated. That works for non-mapreduce projects, but for MapReduce ones, it does not seem to work.

Comment: I traced the code yesterday and it also adds hbase-site.xml as a resource.

Comment: Yeah, but what if ir's not part of the classpath. Then it cannot read it. That's when we manually add it as a resource.

Comment: I tried that too. Manually adding it still didn't load it.

Comment: That's what I was talking about. MAnually adding it loads it for me if I am not doing it in a MapReduce job and I am not sure if it is a bug.